# Questions about solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have encountered a question that goes like

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y^3+x\cos(x),\;y(0)=0.$$

Find the approximate solution which is $o(x^5).$

I think it may need to use the Picard approximation but do not know how to use it. Can anyone help me, appreciate your help.

Comment: The Picard approximation looks like a good try, but even by the second iteration it gets very complicated so that seems unlikely

Comment: How about using the Talor series. Will that help?

Comment: I believe you can do that, yes. I was slow to pick up on that because I didn't think to also replace the $x\cos(x)$ with its power series.

Answer (score 0):

You insert a (truncated) power series up to the 5th order. To determine these coefficients, you need to equate coefficients up to the 4th power in
$$
a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^3+5a_5x^4+o(x^4)=(a_0+a_1x+...+a_4x^4+o(x^4))^3+x-\frac{x^3}2+o(x^4).
$$
As everything goes well in this power series expansion, one could also replace $o(x^4)$ with the sharper $O(x^5)$.